# JasperReport Issue using with struts2 - getting null in final PDF file

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Im writing my jasper report problem with *struts2*. Following is the code that I'm trying to execute :

struts.xml contains :

```xml
<action name="myJasperTest1" class="temp.JasperAction1">
    <result name="success" type="jasper">
        <param name="location">/jasper/our_compiled_template.jasper</param>
        <param name="dataSource">myList</param>
        <param name="format">PDF</param>
    </result>
</action>
```

My JasperAction1 contains :

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import com.sufalam.business.model.util.LegacyJasperInputStream;
import com.sufalam.business.finance.model.bean.Account;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JasperDesign;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader;

public class JasperAction1 extends ActionSupport {

    /** List to use as our JasperReports dataSource. */
    private List<Account> myList;

    public String execute() throws Exception {

        // Create some imaginary persons.
        Account a1 = new Account();
        Account a2 = new Account();

        a1.setId(77);
        a1.setName("aaa");
        a2.setId(88);
        a2.setName("bbb");
        // Store people in our dataSource list (normally would come from database).
        myList = new ArrayList<Account>();
        myList.add(a1);
        myList.add(a2);

        // Normally we would provide a pre-compiled .jrxml file
        // or check to make sure we don't compile on every request.
        try {
            JasperDesign design = JRXmlLoader.load(
                    new LegacyJasperInputStream(new FileInputStream("F://backup//report2.jrxml")));

            JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(design, "F://backup//our_compiled_template1.jasper");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return ERROR;
        }

        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public List<Account> getMyList() {
        return myList;
    }
}
```

I am using *iReport* plugin of *Netbeans* for generation .jrxml file. After Designing my page using *iReport* wizard my our_jasper_template.jrxml file contains following code :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="null" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="535" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <queryString language="SQL">
            <![CDATA[SELECT
         account_master."name" AS account_master_name,
         account_master."id" AS account_master_id
    FROM
         "public"."account_master" account_master]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="account_master_name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="account_master_id" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <title>
        <band height="58">
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="8" width="555" height="1"/>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" x="0" y="51" width="555" height="1"/>
            </line>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="65" y="13" width="424" height="35"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font size="26" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Classic template]]>
                </text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <detail>
        <band height="40">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="139" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[account_master_name]]>
                </text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="139" y="0" width="416" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{account_master_name}]]>
                </textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="20" width="139" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[account_master_id]]>
                </text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="139" y="20" width="416" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.Integer"><![CDATA[$F{account_master_id}]]>
                </textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="26">
            <textField evaluationTime="Report" pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement key="textField" x="516" y="6" width="36" height="19" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["" + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]>
                </textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement key="textField" x="342" y="6" width="170" height="19" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["Page " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER} + " of "]]>
                </textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <reportElement key="textField" x="1" y="6" width="209" height="19" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.util.Date"><![CDATA[new Date()]]>
                </textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
</jasperReport>
```

Now the problem I'm facing is when I execute this action class it gives me following output as pdf format : 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Remove Query string portion from your .jrxml file and change your field name with account class's variable Name.

Answer (score 0):

Although I may not have the final solution, there is a detail that looks odd to me: your fields `account_master_name` and `account_master_id` don't really seem to align with the property names of your Account class. Shouldn't it be `id` and `name`? What's weird to me is that it should generate an error when filling the report...

I am not too familiar with Struts, but I don't see how it can affect.

Comment: ya but i tried to change id & name as a field name. But still i am getting null value as a result not a error while filling report. DEBUG shows me filling : null not the error... Any suggestion from your side ?